# Can I tell eclipse debugger to print to console/log?

Tags: logging, eclipse, console, debug

Related question:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225243/is-printing-to-console-stdout-a-good-debugging-strategy

We have something like this

```
private int myFunction(int i)

{
    //line a
    someCode(); 
    //line b
    someMoreCode();
    //line c
    return v; 
}

private void myMain()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {

     myfunction(i); 
    }
}
```

Now something's going wrong in myFunction, let's say for when i = 6.

The way I see it, I have two options:

- I can add a breakpoint at line a, run the debugger and step return
  till i=6, and look at the values at each line.
- I can go in a put console/stdout statements at lines a, b, c, and get a complete listing/trace of how the variable that I'm interested
  in are changing.

The problem with this second solution, is that I'm then constantly pasting/typing in console statements and then going through an removing them.

What would be a lot easier, is being able to click in breakpoints, and then telling it, which variables I'm interested in, and have the debugger print out those variables, as well as the line number to a log.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to a breakpoint to decide when it becomes active.

Right click on the breakpoint and select `Breakpoint Properties`, select the `Conditional` check box and you will be able to type code - something like:

```
return i == 6;
```

to stop when `i` is 6.

More details in [Java Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced)